# Error while trying to connect MySQL with sqlalchemy (Flask)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I have been looking for this error for a while but nothing seems to solve my problem, the thing is.. 
I was using sqlite3 with flask, but it seems like sqlite3 does not support migrations, so I decided to change to Mysql. I have installed LAMPP, and I created a symbolik link from:

```
/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

to:

```
/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock
```

but still I get this error (it is a little long but the trouble relapse on the last line):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "db_create.py", line 5, in <module>
db.create_all()
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 895, in create_all
self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 887, in _execute_for_all_tables
op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3634, in create_all
tables=tables)
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1851, in _run_visitor
with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1844, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
with self.contextual_connect() as conn:
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2035, in contextual_connect
self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2074, in _wrap_pool_connect
e, dialect, self)
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1405, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
exc_info
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2070, in _wrap_pool_connect
return fn()
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 376, in connect
return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 708, in _checkout
fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 480, in checkout
rec = pool._do_get()
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1055, in _do_get
self._dec_overflow()
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1052, in _do_get
return self._create_connection()
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 323, in _create_connection
return _ConnectionRecord(self)
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 449, in __init__
self.connection = self.__connect()
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 602, in __connect
connection = self.__pool._invoke_creator(self)
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 97, in connect
return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 385, in connect
return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2) 
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

On my research, I found that I have to change the line:

```
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

placed on /etc/mysql/my.cnf to:

```
socket      = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

(The path were "mysql.sock" is located), but still it does not solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: whats the error now ?

Comment: Ok I just made a change on the symbolik link and now I have a different error.. here it is:
   `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:(_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1044, "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database '/home/gerardo/Documentos/python_web_dev/flask-intro/app.db'")`


and the database URI:
`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql:///' + \
        os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')`

Comment: delete the socket file(mysql.sock) and retstart MYSQL server

Comment: @Code-Monk I did what you said and I get the same error I've mentioned on the comment above (so it seems like it is working, now the thing is about the permission)

Comment: Try `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost/database'` where `database` is the name of your database.

Comment: It's working now ! (I think), I changed all the lines `socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` on /etc/mysql/my.cnf, to my path where "mysql.sock" were. I just had changed one line before. Now I get the next error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database 'app3.db'")`
but.. if no database is founded, is not created automatically  ?? @doru

Answer (score 0):

In the database configuration. Replace localhost with `127.0.0.1`:

`environ.get('APP_DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost')`

to

`environ.get('APP_DATABASE_HOST', '127.0.0.1')`