# Can't connect to mysql on localhost using Docker

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have made a very simple flask app that checks if the username and password combination exists in the database and returns the name of the person. I basically wanted to try out Docker. My application uses sqlalchemy to connect to the database.

Every time I try to connect the docker image to the database using docker run the following error is shown.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

These are the contents of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

This is what my requirements.txt contains:

```
Flask==0.10.1
mysqlclient
sqlalchemy
```

If I try to run the app as is without Docker, it runs as is. As far as I understand, there is no need to specify any port nos as Docker is communicating on to the outside. I don't understand what I am missing, please help.

Comment: See these links: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/3618/ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556365/error-while-trying-to-connect-mysql-with-sqlalchemy-flask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Error 2002 SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209514/docker-error-2002-sqlalchemy)

Comment: @Dalton, none of the above links are like my problem. I can connect to a database that is external to my computer from within docker(I connected to a database hosted on AWS RDS), but i cannot connect to the database on my localhost, which is what I have been trying to do. The database on localhost is not hosted on docker.

Comment: How are you trying to access the database in your host? What address/IP are you using? Did you ping your host from your container?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to connect to the database from within the container. I installed mysqlclient in the container and tried to connect to the localhost database using 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, localhost. But still I am unable to connect from within the docker container. I think the problem can be solved if i get the correct IP, but I  dont know where to find it.

Comment: Yes. It will not work because you are using "localhost", "127.0.0.1", "0.0.0.0" that are addresses to "container localhost"! You have to use the host IP. Try it...

Comment: @Dalton can you give me a clue as to where to find it? I tried ifconfig on the localhost and tried to connect to all the IPs given from within the docker container, but still not working.

Comment: Did you use the exact host IP? See this to see if it helps: https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-machine-from-within-docker-container/14248/13